# R Markdown (Rmd) hide a paragraph of general text based on condition

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I am working on an Rmd down report and depending on an R variable I want to decide whether to include a paragraph or not

e.g.

```
##Abstract
paragraph Blurb

If result type is 1 then
another paragraph of blurb
```

I can't find any easy way to do this.  I've tried using a code chunk.

e.g

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
    if ( resultType1 ) {
        cat(c("lines of blurb","more lines of blurb"))
    }
```
````

Unfortunately, this outputs the optional paragraph in a box plus in a totally different font from the general abstract paragraph and has a feel of surely there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what about using `results='asis'` in the code chunk header.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
if ( resultType1 ) {
  cat(c("lines of blurb","more lines of blurb"))
}
```
````

It is also possible to print headlines with ## etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using an R chunk and `cat()` does not work when the text has some LaTeX commands.

Instead, and courtesy of [this solution][1] you can simply use the asis engine directly, e.g.:

````
```{asis, echo=resultType1}
lines of blurb
more lines of blurb
even more lines of blurb including an equation: $\hat{y} = \hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}X_1$
````

```
  [1]: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/113
```